# Explanation to understand what this regex is doing in this code

Tags: javascript, regex

I would love to understand what these four lines doing, two contain regex:

```
text.replace(/\W/g, " ")
text.split(/\s+/);
text.filter(v => !!v)
text.reduce((dict, v) => {dict[v] = v in dict ? dict[v] + 1 : 1; return dict}, {});
```

I understand the result would be something like `{happy: 5, love: 3}`. However, could someone explain to me in detail what each line is doing.

Comment: there are some assignments missing, it looks more than a chained approach.

Comment: Reason for down voting my comment? It doesn't seem very wise to do that without giving me an explanation. How would I ever learn for next time?

Comment: At a guess, the downvote is because the question doesn't show a lot of effort, but asks for a substantial effort ("explain everything") of readers. The questions that are the most well-received are the ones that have clearly taken a lot of effort to compile or research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is used to count words in a text.

The 1st RegExp `.replace(/\W/g, " ")` convert non word characters (not numbers, letters, or underscore) to spaces.

The 2nd RegExp splits the text using sequences of spaces as the delimiter.

Since all actions produce new strings/arrays/objects, you'll need to store the results in a variable, or chain the methods.

```js
var text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempor risus eu nisl pretium ultrices. Vivamus a malesuada est. Donec fringilla pharetra dolor, vitae mattis lorem pulvinar sit amet. Sed tristique tellus sit amet maximus rhoncus. Vestibulum accumsan quam in ligula finibus fermentum.";

var result = text.replace(/\W/g, " ") // convert all now word characters to spaces
  .split(/\s+/) // split with continuous spaces as the delimeter 
  .filter(v => !!v) // filter falsy values, ie 0 probably in this case
  .reduce((dict, v) => {dict[v] = v in dict ? dict[v] + 1 : 1; return dict}, {}); // count the number of times a word appears
  
console.log(result);
```

You can combine the 2 RegExps into a single `.match(/\w+/g)` - get an array of all word sequences:

```js
var text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempor risus eu nisl pretium ultrices. Vivamus a malesuada est. Donec fringilla pharetra dolor, vitae mattis lorem pulvinar sit amet. Sed tristique tellus sit amet maximus rhoncus. Vestibulum accumsan quam in ligula finibus fermentum.";

var result = text.match(/\w+/g) // get all word sequences
  .filter(v => !!v) // filter falsy values, ie 0 probably in this case
  .reduce((dict, v) => {dict[v] = v in dict ? dict[v] + 1 : 1; return dict}, {}); // count the number of times a word appears
  
console.log(result);
```